# Detect iOS orientation relative to the home button in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ios, orientation

How can I detect an iOS devices orientation relative it's home button in JavaScript?

Comment: using `window.orientation`: `90`: button on the right, `-90`: button on the left, `0`: button at the bottom, `180`: button at the top.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, you can use window.orientation. For example:

```
switch(window.orientation)
                {
                    case 0:
                        //"Portrait"
                    break;

                    case -90:
                        //"Landscape (right, screen turned clockwise)"
                    break;

                    case 90:
                        //"Landscape (left, screen turned counterclockwise)"
                    break;

                    case 180:
                        //"Portrait (upside-down portrait)"
                    break;

                }
```

For more information see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html)

Comment: Thanks! http://www.williammalone.com/articles/html5-javascript-ios-orientation/ this is also good.